# Blender 2.8 - how do I delete objects in its entirety from a scene at a certain frame

Tags: keyframes, rigidbody

I have rigid bodies in the middle of my animation scene but I want them to disappear because I have a giant rigid body falling on top and want it to squish the other rigid bodies.  I thought it'd be good if I can delete the tiny RB's 1 frame before the GIANT one lands on them but there doesn't seem to be a way to do that.  I've tried the render (camera) keyframe and the GIANT rb still thinks it's there and bounces on top of the tiny (now invisible) RBs.

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: I just move them out of frame within one frame

Comment: looks like the Visibility - Show in Renders is animatable.

Comment: that would be done with render layers in 2.79, but in Blender 2.80 you use View layers.  Unfortunately, I still don't understand view layers very well.